# Revoke FTP permissions to subfolder for a certain user

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I'm working in a web project to which several people can access to the FTP.
There is a particular user that should no access to a certain sub-folder, so I would like to revoke the access to it.

The server uses vsFTPd

As far as I see this can be achieved using "setfacl". So in order to avoid the user "mywebpage_johndoe" to access to the folder "foo/" I've tried this:

`setfacl -R -m u:mywebpage_johndoe:--- /home/mywebpage/mwebpage.net/public_html/foo/`

But this does not seem to work and when I test the permissions with "getfacl" I noticed this:

```
# file: home/mywebpage/webpage.net/public_html/foo/
# owner: mywebpage
# group: mywebpage
user::rwx
user:mywebpage:---
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

So either the command has issues with the underscore or I'm missing something.

Could please anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The user could still have permissions via the group.

Comment: @DanielB thanks, that's a good point. Maybe I'm using the wrong approach. I don't know if this is even possible. Any suggestion?